# Appstream not connecting on android device's Chrome browser

Tags: aws-appstream

I have created a project that uses Amazon Appstream SDK for .net. I am able to access the streaming application on Windows desktop chrome browser. However, when I try same on Android mobile (latest chrome version) the appstream does not connect to the app.

It displays the following error:

[image]

The version of chrome/browser is same (the latest one) both on desktop and android mobile.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try "request desktop site" in the sidebar.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support zooming however.